# post to twitter using OAuth in iphone..?

Tags: iphone, facebook, twitter

how to post to twitter using OAuth..??  i have tried the sample applications but they open the twitter site for login.(username/password)...
but i want is ..i want to store the twitter details at the settings page..

i just want to post the text written in text field..i dont want to login every time ...i want it to be simple..two text fields for username and password and one for message..?can it be possible..??

i want the similar app for facebook for posting on wall..i downloaded the facebook sample app but the problem is each time user had to enter password and the message to be posted is his own dialog box (not the simple text field)..?

Answer (score 1):

You can not store username and password with OAuth.

Comment: no i just want to fill them from my View controller once..and when needed application can check from there..in the apps i tried i have to fill them in the twitter page..

Comment: This OAuth all about... you can not store credentials for sites in your app... from the wiki page - OAuth (Open Authorization) is an open standard for authorization. It allows users to share their private resources (e.g. photos, videos, contact lists) stored on one site with another site without having to hand out their credentials, typically username and password.

Comment: You are not allowed to STORE or even ASK the user on twitter or facebook for their password.